# CSS Grayscale Filter + Colored Gradient

Tags: css, css-filters

I'm trying to create, with pure CSS, an effect where:

1. A color background image is grayscaled and has a gradient applied to it; and
2. On hover, the gradient fades out and the color fades in.

Below, I've tried two techniques, each of which seems to solve half the issue. The fallback would be to make color and grayscale versions of the image, but obviously I'd like to avoid that to minimize load times. Would appreciate any thoughts you guys might have - I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks!

**Technique 1: Gradient plus Background-Blend-Mode**

Here, I've applied the gradient to the background image directly and the grayscale effect is achieved with the combination of a white background and the background-blend-mode property.

This results in an overall darker image, but that's fine - the bigger problem is that the transition doesn't appear to work, and so the image jumps from one mode to the other instantly rather than through a slow fade.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lparts4j/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 80%), url("http://i.imgur.com/ulb7EVg.jpg");
  background-color: white;
  background-blend-mode: multiply, luminosity;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out; }

.test:hover {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ulb7EVg.jpg");
  background-color: white;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
  background-size: cover; }
```

**Technique 2: Grayscale Filter plus Gradient in :Before Element**

Here, I've applied the gradient with a :before element, and the grayscale effect is achieved with the filter property.

The fade works with this approach. However, I'm unable to combine the gradient with the grayscale - the grayscale filter ends up applying to the :before element as well, such that the gradient loses all color.

In the jsfiddle, the left image has both gradient and grayscale filter, while the right image has gradient alone.

https://jsfiddle.net/548afgjf/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="img img-one"></div>
<div class="img img-two"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px; }

.img-one {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ulb7EVg.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.img-one:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    background: rgb(0, 47, 75);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgb(0, 47, 75)), color-stop(100%, rgb(220, 66, 37)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#002f4b', endColorstr='#dc4225', GradientType=1);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
}
.img-one:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.img-one:hover:before {
    opacity: 0; }

.img-two {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ulb7EVg.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.img-two:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    background: rgb(0, 47, 75);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgb(0, 47, 75)), color-stop(100%, rgb(220, 66, 37)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0, 47, 75) 0%, rgb(220, 66, 37) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#002f4b', endColorstr='#dc4225', GradientType=1);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
}
.img-two:hover {
}
.img-two:hover:before {
    opacity: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow! We're both trying to do almost the same exact thing. Since pseudo elements seem to inherit filters, I separated them by adding the background img and grayscale filter to :before, and then the gradient to :after. On hover the :before filter changes to zero, and the :after gradient fades to opacity zero. It seems to work, except now I'm researching some type of white backface that pops up. You don't have that issue, so you may be a step ahead of me in that regard ;)  Your fiddle also fades fine for me, so either you fixed it or it's a browser issue? http://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/VLYPyq/

Comment: Chase, I think we might have it. That white flicker is related to the backface and seems to only arise in Webkit browsers. Add "-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d" to your class. Of course, now I have to deal with the IE issue, but the answer below might give a lead.

Comment: Awesome! I tried backface-visibility with no luck, and wrongly decided preserve-3d was unrelated since I'm not manipulating perspective on anything. Clearly I was wrong! Now that I'm looking into IE, NO versions support blend modes, which really sucks. You can blend SVG filters, but no IE support for that either. Though, Jeff is right about the grayscale. So far, the closest I'm getting is an inline img, SVG filter that sets it to grayscale, :after element with gradient, and a css background img. Then fade the SVG and :after on hover, revealing the full color background. Check the pen again.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried to do the greyscale effect in the past, and the only way I could get it to work across all browsers was to wrap the image in an SVG element, and apply SVG filters to the element.  You may need to do the same for this to work.

On your page you'll need to define the SVG filter (this just does greyscale... you'd need to research how to also colorize... )

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="greyscale">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
      0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
      0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
      0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Next wrap your image in an SVG element:

```
<svg class="filterThis" width="100px" height="100px">
  <image class="svgImg" xlink:href="image.png" height="100px" width="100px" />
</svg>
```

And apply the filter in your CSS:

```
svg.filterThis .svgImg {
  filter: url(#greyscale);
}
```

Comment: one should avoid using `xlink:href` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href).